# AngularJS Count - How many times x.status == 10

Tags: json, angularjs, count

I have 3 diffrent status. 10, 20 and 30.

I want to count how many times x.status == 10 and then show it

I thought something like this

count="x.status" where="x.status == 10"

count :{{value}}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


</head>
<body ng-app>

    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">


        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in Id">
                <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.number }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.resource }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.created }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.status }}</td>


            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    <script>
    function customersController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("mylocalhost")
        .success(function (response) { $scope.Id = response });

    }




    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">


        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in Id">
                <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.number }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.resource }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.created }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.status }}</td>


            </tr>
        </table>
Status 10 : {{status10 }} | Status 20 : {{status20 }} | Status 30 : {{status30 }} | 
    </div>
```

JS:

```
  function customersController($scope, $http) {
        $scope.status10 = 0;
        $scope.status20 = 0;
        $scope.status30 = 0;

        $http.get("mylocalhost")
            .success(function (response) {
            $scope.Id = response;

            angular.forEach($scope.Id, function (value) {

                switch (value.status) {
                    case 10:
                        $scope.status10++;
                        break;
                    case 20:
                        $scope.status20++;
                        break;
                    case 30:
                        $scope.status30++;
                        break;

                    default:
                        console.log(value.status);


                }


            });

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let it be simple unless you are super-focused on performance.

```
{{(data|filter:{'key':value}).length}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/aKR3PCJs8mLTdKGo09YQ?p=preview

```
Number of all friends: {{friends.length}}     <br />
How many John? {{(friends|filter:{'name':'John'}).length}}  <br/>
How many foo? {{(friends|filter:{'name':'foo'}).length}}  <br/>
```